# policy based management, sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I need to prepare policy that returns all the tables with a OLD update statistic date and a another policy that return ERRORs in the errorlogs related the servers

policy management

i need to create policies in ssms-->management-->policy management-->policies(I need to create two policies related to return all the tables with old update statistic date(approx 60 days) and a policy to show the sql server error logs like 0,1 ;failed ). please help

I have tried to use the inbuilt statistics facet for the old updated statistics and condition I have mentioned as lastdate!=09/01/2017 and created policy for it, it got evaluated succesfully.
Now I need to add a code that will check the last updated stats on the table, when I'm trying to use the below code in condition it is showing error as error parsing make sue that string contraints are closed in single quotes and facet property set to @, I have done this but still receiving same error message. Please help

```
 ExecuteSQL('Numeric','SELECT DISTINCT
OBJECT_NAME(s.[object_id]) AS TableName,
c.name AS ColumnName,
s.name AS StatName,
s.auto_created,
s.user_created,
s.no_recompute,
par.[rows],
s.[object_id],
s.stats_id,
sc.stats_column_id,
sc.column_id,
STATS_DATE(s.[object_id], s.stats_id) AS LastUpdated 
FROM sys.stats s JOIN sys.stats_columns sc ON sc.[object_id] = s.[object_id] AND sc.stats_id = s.stats_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.[object_id] = sc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = sc.column_id
JOIN sys.partitions par ON par.[object_id] = s.[object_id] 
JOIN sys.objects obj ON par.[object_id] = obj.[object_id] WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(s.OBJECT_ID,'IsUserTable') = 1
AND (s.auto_created = 1 OR s.user_created = 1)
and rows > 100')
```

Comment: Add extra quotes aounrd `'IsUserTable'` so it reads `WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(s.OBJECT_ID,''IsUserTable'') = 1`  Note that I've added extra single quotes, they are not double quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll follow the instructions provided by and get back to you.

Comment: Also I want to create a policy for sql server error logs in the policy management. can you please help me with this

Comment: Sorry, I only spotted the error in your code. I know nothing about policies..